# Project Euler #3 double division

Tags: java

I'm currently working on Project's Euler Problem 3 and due to lacking programming skills, I keep failing.
The mean thing about that Problem is, that the number is too huge for int.
Therefore I used double. Sadly my whole code is based on whole division.

`

```
public static ArrayList PrimeDeco(double Insert, int Position, ArrayList PrimeFactor){
    ArrayList<Integer> Prime= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Prime=Primenumbers(1000);
    int i = Position;
    while(Insert%(Integer)Prime.get(i)==0){
        Insert=Insert/Prime.get(i);
    }
    PrimeFactor.add((Integer)Prime.get(Position));
    System.out.println(PrimeFactor);

    if(Insert!=1){
    System.out.println(Insert + " "  + Position);
    PrimeDeco(Insert,Position+1, PrimeFactor);

    }
    return PrimeFactor;
}
```

Where as Insert is of type double and Prime.get(i) a Primenumber.
While working for example with Integer 70, my programm prints [2,5,7]
woth the Division 70, 35, 7, 1. But obviously that doesnt work with double type numbers and I don't know how to get a whole number without comma out of double.

Comment: Why can't you just call `Primenumbers(Math.round(Math.sqrt(600851475143)))`? Please explain what your code is intended to do, and why.

Answer (score 2):

Use `long` instead of `int` or `double`. `long` is a datatype which can store integer values up to 2^64 (2^63-1).

You can also use `BigInteger` which is an object that can store integers of any size.